# VS2010: Can a keyboard shortcut run more than one command?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to assign more than one command to a keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio 2010?

What I really want to do is this:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> : Save current file, run an External Tool

(Essentially the same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a small Visual Studio macro with two calls to DTE.ExecuteCommand and assign your Ctrl-B shortcut to this macro.

Comment: Yes, DTE.ExecuteCommand("File.SaveSelectedItems"). You can see command names in Visual Studio keyboard options.